# dotnet build ignore --framework param for projects with only FrameworkTarget

Tags: .net-core

I work with .NET Core SDK version `2.1.302`. My solution has two type of projects: libraries and web. All libraries are targeted to .NET Standard 2.0: `<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>` and web projects have multiple targets: `<TargetFrameworks>net462;netcoreapp2.0</TargetFrameworks>`

I have two CI builds: for Windows which uses net462 and build in docker based on linux with netcoreapp2.0.

In the docker build to build my solution I use the following line of code:

```
RUN dotnet build ./MySolution.sln --configuration Release --framework netcoreapp2.0
```

And build fails with the rrors like this:

> Assets file '/app/MyLibraryProject/obj/project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'netcoreapp2.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project. [/app/MyLibraryProject.csproj]

It happens because as I mentioned before my library projects are targeted only one framework - netstandard2.0

So, my question is how to deal with this situation? How should I specify that projects with only one target framework should ignore --framework param?

Comment: There are 2 options for this I think: build the main project instead of the solution, or use msbuild to define the target framework based on the environment (you can use `$(OS)`, or pass some custom property in the `dotnet build` command).

Comment: I do not want to use separate project builds, because I also have test projects which I should build separately too. After adding new project I should change my build scripts again. Looks like a lot of work. What about custom parameter: it looks possible to use it, but maybe I just miss a more simple solution with built-in keys like `--framework`

Comment: The second option is basically using a custom parameter, for example `RUN dotnet build ./MySolution.sln --configuration Release /p:BuildCoreOnly=True`. You just need to add conditional properties to the project, like `<TargetFramework Condition="'$(BuildCoreOnly)' == 'True'">netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the interests of making sure the answer is noticed, I found that the best way around this was @José Pedro's solution from the above comment stream.

In the csproj file, I put a condition on the `TargetFramework` element.  Now it looks as follows:

```xml
<TargetFrameworks Condition="'$(CoreOnly)' != 'True'">net472;netcoreapp2.1</TargetFrameworks>
<TargetFramework Condition="'$(CoreOnly)' == 'True'">netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
```

It will then by default compile both, but you can pass a `CoreOnly` parameter to only compile the .NET Core framework.

`dotnet build MySolution.sln /p:CoreOnly=True`

Comment: Can't try your solution because my project fully migrated to the .NET Core and I haven't this problem anymore but it looks like this trick should work. Thank you!

Comment: I use this trick to build for both netcoreapp2.1 and netcoreapp3.1 target frameworks in parallel builds and it really works. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to check which framework is available and set the `<TargetFramework>` dynamically in the build time:

```
<FrameworkDescription>$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::FrameworkDescription)</FrameworkDescription>
<TargetFramework Condition="$(FrameworkDescription.Contains('NET 5'))">net5</TargetFramework>
<TargetFramework Condition="$(FrameworkDescription.Contains('NET 7'))">net7</TargetFramework>
```

It will make `dotnet build` just work without any additional parameters on a system where only net5 or only net7 is installed.